# Hotkey to undo autocompletion in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

Example: when you want to type single left quote, doublequote, bracket, curly bracket etc... at once right element is inserted by IDE automatically.

It was expected that simple ctrl+z combination would remove autocompletion but it wouldn't.

Because of that I have to press right arrow plus backspace and it slows down type performance significantly.

Is there related hotkey?

I'm using IDEA 14.

Answer (score 0):

Using <kbd>delete</kbd> instead of <kbd>-></kbd> and <kbd>backspace</kbd> you have single press of a key.

Alternatively, you can turn automatic insertion in settings:

[image]

Comment: You are right, this can be done by single "delete" pressing :-). Why I'm using another combination because "delete" button is much smaller on my laptop keyboard and it is much harder to hit it without looking at the keyboard.